# D3, have the color of slices customised

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using D3. I would like the colors of the slices the piechart to be for example dark yellow, yellow, lighter yellow, lighter lighter yellow etc depending on how many data I have.

After looking the documentation I came across the d3.scale.category10 , d3.scale.category20 etc. but these are offering many different colours instead of one that fades out.

Can someone help?

Thanks guys
Nick

Comment: You can specify your own colours or colour scale.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Could you give me an example of a colour scale like my example ?

Comment: See e.g. http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/07/08/quick-custom-colour-scales-in-d3js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Lars Kotthoff and some extra researching I came down to this:

```
  var myColors = ["#f5800a","#ff8000","#ff8a14", "#ff9427", "#ff9d3b", "#ffa74e","#ffb162", "#ffbb76", "#ffc489", "#ffce9d", "#ffd8b1", "#ffe2c4","#ffebd8","fff5eb"];

d3.scale.myColors = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal().range(myColors);
};
```

and at the end append the custom colors to `.showLabels(false).color(d3.scale.myColors().range())`

So I am creating an array of custom colors , then I am putting that as the range of colors and finally I am adding the range as an option of the colors of the bar chart.

Hopes that helps other people as well.